# Android multi-touch interference

Tags: android, multi-touch

I'm currently developing an air-hockey simulation for android. For the multiplayer mode I'm tracking two touch events on the screen, which works well as long as the touch points don't get to close.
[image: Normal Touch]

When the two fingers get to close, android only recognizes one touch event, in the middle of both points.

[image: Two events overlapping]

To make it even worse, android sometimes messes up the IDs after the collision.

[image: Wrong IDs assigned]

I already thought about estimating the next touch points ans assigning IDs manually, does anybody know a better way, or knows about somebody who already fixed this problem programmatically?

NOTE: I'm testing on a Samsung Galaxy S 3

Comment: Did you try the gesture handling Android 4.0? From what I can see, it looks like you're still handling touch/gestures in the Android 2.3 SDK  manner. Just a shot in the dark :)

Comment: What's the difference between both? The pictures are just screenshots of the android touch gesture debugger.

Comment: +1 for well explain issue

Answer (score 6):

Not necessarily a logical fix to the issue, nevertheless a possible solution to the application:

If I'm not completely mistaken, air-hockey games shouldn't allow opponents to intrude on each others game field. If we assume a thick border cross the center of the screen (in portrait mode), then I wouldn't be allowed to do anything beyond that border, hence there is no point in tracking my finger after it reaches the border line.

Encapsulating your tracked touch events into valid physical locations as described might just help you in ignoring invalid points (given that the physical locations doesn't intersect, that is).

You might also have to keep track of direction of the touch vector: if the vector is stretching from the center of the screen towards "your end" it might be the opponents intruding finger or your own returning finger. In neither case should they affect the hockey puck (perhaps).

Comment: Limiting the player's movement to their field is a good idea. And a thick border may stop the players from trying to move beyond it psychologically ;)

Answer (score 2):

It may depend on the device you are using, but I'm using the code below in a Huawei X5 and It never mess up fingers, even if they touch each other or it I twist them over the screen.

```
private static PointF touchScreenStartPtArr[] = new PointF[10];
private static PointF touchScreenStopPtArr[] = new PointF[10];
private static PointF touchScreenCurrPtArr[] = new PointF[10];

OnTouchListener onTouchListenerMulti = new OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        int action = event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;
        int pointerIndex = (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_MASK) >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT;
        int fingerId = event.getPointerId(pointerIndex);

        switch (action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
            touchScreenStartPtArr[fingerId].x = event.getX(pointerIndex);
            touchScreenStartPtArr[fingerId].y = event.getY(pointerIndex);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            touchScreenStopPtArr[fingerId].x = event.getX(pointerIndex);
            touchScreenStopPtArr[fingerId].y  = event.getX(pointerIndex);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            int pointerCount = event.getPointerCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < pointerCount; i++) {
                touchScreenCurrPtArr[fingerId].x = event.getX(i);
                touchScreenCurrPtArr[fingerId].y = event.getY(i);
            }
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }
};
```

Note that I'm using fingerId and not pointerId to identify the correct finger, as pointer id may change when one finger is released.

Hope it works for you.

Comment: As @heycosmo already mentioned, there is a touchscreen resolution, which causes touch events, which are to close together, to be seen as one. Your solution doesn't solve this problem.

Comment: Theoretically you can imagine the @heycosmo description to be a physical representation of reality in which you would have a finger one pixel wide. That's not the case, your finger touch several pixels at same time, and will will never be able to touch to adjacent pixels witn two different fingers, because your finger is several pixels wide and have round ending. It's up to the device driver the way it's interpreting this mutliple points pressed at once by each finger. I can assure you that the code above works flawlessly in my device. It's not possible to make it mess fingers, no mater what.

Comment: By the way, it's not exactly thes same problem you have, but have some common issues in here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12500465/android-multi-touch-interference/12645449#comment17065729_12645449 It has been solved with the suggestion above. good luck

Comment: Android dispatches a ACTION_POINTER_UP Event for one of the both fingers when they get to close, so your method doesn't deliver separate points either. And your link doesn't seem to work :(

Comment: Sorry about the link. This is the correct one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12590738/android-multitouch-cant-move-2-pointers-at-same-time/12592940#12592940 . As I said, it may depend on the specific driver used by your device. I've used the code above in several applications, and after your comments I've tried to have it failing moving the fingers as close as possible, pressing one against the other and twisting them and it doesn't fail in my device. By the way, have you tried my suggestion just for the sake of confirmation?

Comment: I sent all events to logcat and received only one touch point when my fingers got to close. Your solution caches the positions, but that doesn't hinder android from confusing the pointerIds of the fingers. So after coming to close, in some cases, the new positions are saved at the wrong index. Probably Huawei has a better driver or better touchscreens than Samsung.

Comment: Sorry that it didn't help :-(. Just for confirmation, when you say pointers id for the finger, you are refering the fingerId in the above code, not the pointerIndex. Correct? Because the pointerIndex also change in my device, but the fingerId remains correct.

Comment: Jep. Thanks for trying to help :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's the way I see it.

The touchscreen hardware gives you a resolution below which two touches are the same as one. This is something you cannot change.

Now the question is, what to do when two touches merge? (This is something that can be tested for programmatically one would think; e.g. if 2 touch pts -> 1 touch pt. AND prev touch pt 1 is close enough to prev touch pt 2...). In your case, I would move both pucks along the merged touch gesture until they separate, then return individual control.

Of course, I see several problems with this, like which touch controls which puck after the split? Maybe one person lifted their finger during the merge.

You could have both players lose control of their puck if a merge occurs. This could simulate the shock to the wrist as your hand bashes into your opponent's :)

I also like @dbm idea.

Hope this helps. Probably didn't :)