# OnTouch with multitouch in android

Tags: android, ontouchlistener

I am havig troubles counting how much touches are being made in each "half" of the screen. 
When I touch in the upper side it counts correctly, and the same with the lower side. BUT, when I touch the upper side, dont release it, and touch the lower side, then it counts the wrong side, what is wrong in my implementation?

```
     myView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                int action = event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;
                if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    if(event.getY()<400)
                    {


                    }
                    else
                    {

                    }
                }

                if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

                    if(event.getY()<400)
                    {

                        zenbat=zenbat+1;
                        tv.setText(String.valueOf(zenbat));

                    }
                    if(event.getY()>400)
                    {
                        zenbat1=zenbat1+1;
                        tv1.setText(String.valueOf(zenbat1));

                    }
                }

                if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN) {
                    if(event.getY()<400)
                    {                           
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    }
                }

                if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP) {
                    if(event.getY()<400)
                    {
                        zenbat=zenbat+1;
                        tv.setText(String.valueOf(zenbat));

                    }
                    if(event.getY()>400)
                    {
                        zenbat1=zenbat1+1;
                        tv1.setText(String.valueOf(zenbat1));

                    }
                } 
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Comment: On the `ACTION_POINTER_DOWN` that occurs when you still have a finger down on the upper half, it may be finding the coordinates of the midpoint between your two fingers. Android multitouch is finicky

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to correctly handle multitouch events you need to use the pointer index to correctly identify the finger generating the event.

I've answered a similar question in [Android multi-touch interference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12500465/android-multi-touch-interference/12645449#12645449) where I posted a code example how to do it.

To correctly identify the finger, you should refer to the `fingerId` in the code posted.

Regards.